# Laravel loading helper not automatically

Tags: laravel, helper

I tried to load my helper without composer autoload

For controllers I use:

```
use \App\Helper;
```

Works good, But for blade's view how can I load it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it 2 ways

Solution 1: make aliases

In `config\app.php` change `aliases` to

```
'aliases' => [
    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    ...................
    'Helper' => App\Helper::class,
]
```

in blade use

```
@php
    $result = Helper::staticFunction();
    // or
    $helper = app(Helper::class);
    $helper->functionName(); 
@endphp
```

Solution 2:

```
@php
    $result = \App\Helper::staticFunction();
    // ot
    $helper = app(\App\Helper::class);
    $helper->functionName();
@endphp
```

Answer (score 2):

in blade view you can use as **\App\Helper::call();**

```
@php
    $var = \App\Helper::call();
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

try to clear caches

`php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear`